# is there a way package C libary with header

Tags: c, linux, gcc, static-libraries

I'm making a library in C. Now I am about to deliver it to my tester and a problem arises.

I have to ship both my .a library and quite a lot of header files. Those header files appeared to be very inconvenience to use for the tester. Is there anyway to reduce the amount of files need to deliver so it is easier to move around and setup? (e.g pack all header files into 1 or something like that)

Comment: Can’t you create a .dll file by compiling your library ?

Comment: How about a simple zip-file, or since you're on Linux a tar file? Put the headers in one directory, and the library in another, and add the directories to the archive.

Comment: Normally you would archive your library together with the headers in one file. For instance using zip or tar or something like that.

Comment: How exactly are the header files inconvenient for the user?

Comment: Traditionally a library has one header file exposing everything in that library. One header for every object in the archive is less common. This may mean writing a new header file for the API, but normally that's written while developing the library itself.

Comment: @UnholySheep In the same sense as why we prefer the whole library in a file rather than a bunch of object files. I know I should have foreseen this and written the API in a single header file, but now I want to fix it

Comment: Why not add a header file that `#include`s all relevant header files? This is IMHO the cleanest solution, as textual replication (a typical [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) violation) will eventually lead to nasty interface problems. The amount of files shouldn't be the problem, just the amount to take into consideration when using the library, which should be reduced to one.

Comment: If your header files only declares function, without refering to standard headers, you can try using the `gcc` preprocessor: have a `all.c` just including headers, and run `gcc -E` on it: `gcc-E all.c | grep -v "^#" > all.h`

Comment: You might consider making your library free software on http://github.com/ and have your tester also use its compilation and installing procedure.

Comment: That's how all C libraries ship. You may pack your headers and binaries in some sort of archive, but in the end of the day it has to be unpacked. Some unpack to standard places like /usr/lib and /usr/include, but this is not appropriate for untested software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way of delivering software (including libraries) on Linux is using packages (such as RPM on Red Hat/CentOS or DEB on Debian/Ubuntu). It will require some additional effort from you (learning to use some new tools, writing an rpm/deb spec, etc), but it will pay off:

- packages include version numbers, so it will be easy to track, what exactly you are testing
- packages allow you to install files into directories specified by you (e.g. `/usr/include` for headers, `/usr/lib` for libraries).
- if you manage to set up a private package repository, your testers will be able to install/upgrade/downgrade the library using standard Linux tools like `apt-get` or `yum`.

As for minimizing the number of headers, a common practice is to split headers into two subsets: interface headers (that define the API of your library) and internal headers (that declare functions and types used internally, implementation details). Only the former need to be installed. Example: **[libjpegturbo](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo)**. This repository has many header files, but the corresponding [package](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/libjpeg-turbo-devel-1.2.90-5.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) for CentOS 7 only installs 4 headers).

If that is not enough, you could simply concatenate all your interface headers into one big header (it should work, provided that the order is correct). **Googletest** library uses a python [script](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/scripts/fuse_gtest_files.py) to merge their headers  (and sources too).

Comment: Packages should *not* install under `/usr/local/` which is reserved for *unpackaged* software by the [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)

Comment: Right. Installing into /usr/local is a bad habit/convention from my previous job.